# Get modulo from two 4x64bit integer arrays

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, opencl

I use OpenCL for GPGPU programming, but unfortunately there's no native 256 bit integer support. I decided to have 256 bit integer splitted in four 64bit integers. Pretty good solution for basic operations, but how can I get modulo of them?

I need to do this:

```
(uint256) % (uint256)
```

But with OpenCL, I can only have this:

```
[ (uint64), (uint64), (uint64), (uint64) ] % [ (uint64), (uint64), (uint64), (uint64) ]
```

So how can I achieve that? What algorithm should I use, and the most important - what is the easiest to implement?

P.S. I need that for public key cryptography.

**EDIT**: I don't have neither addition nor subtraction implemented.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any recommended reads?

Comment: Can you do what you want with a pencil?  Find a rubber ducky ... talk slowly ...  Have you consider some of the extended precision libraries?  So ... it looks like you have not tried anything as yet.  Please review [mre].

Comment: I tried to search it on google, but I haven't found anything. OpenCL is not like C/C++, and there are no libraries like gmp and others.

Comment: "I don't have neither addition nor subtraction implemented." --> Do you need help with addition?

Comment: With addition an subtraction. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Try [GNU Multiprecision](https://gmplib.org/) gmp library, that has everything you need already implemented, and is the basis of a lot of cryptographic library code.

Comment: I use OpenCL C, and there's no such meaning as libraries. Of course I would have used it if I was working with C/C++.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an easy (and fairly efficient) algorithm that computes the `a % b` using only subtraction, multiplication by 2, division by 2 and comparison (all of them easy to implement for your uint256).

```
uint256 modulo(uint256 a, uint256 b) {
  int i = 0;
  while (b <= a) {
    b = b * 2; // watch out for overflow!
    i++;
  }
  while (i--) {
    b = b / 2;
    if (b <= a) {
      a = a - b;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Here's an example:

```
start: a = 40, b = 7
i = 1, a = 40, b = 14
i = 2, a = 40, b = 28
i = 3, a = 40, b = 56

i = 3, b = 28, a = 40 - 28 = 12
i = 2, b = 14, a = 12 (b > a so nothing happens)
i = 1, b = 7, a = 12 - 7 = 5
i = 0, so we stop and return a = 5
```

EDIT: Why this works?
The naive way of computing the modulo residue if the following:

```
int modulo(int a, int b) {
  while (a >= b) {
    a -= b;
  }
  return a;
}
```

The proposed solution uses the same idea, but in a more efficient way. We know that we will end up with subtracting `b` from `a` exactly `k` times. By we don't know the value of `k`. `k` can be represented in binary as `2^0 * k_0 + 2^1 * k_1 + 2^2 * k_2 + ...`. The algorithm goes from the biggest values of 2^i and tries to subtract `2^i * b`. Thanks to that we achieve logarithmic time complexity instead of linear.

Disclaimer: I Wouldn't use this implementation is real cryptography implementation as it's prone to side channel attacks (different execution time depending on the input).

Comment: Well, I've asked how to implement modulo for two 4x64bit integer arrays, not for two uint256. The point is that I can work only with 64 bit integers.

Comment: @AlexanderSadovskyi You mentioned that "Pretty good solution for basic operations", so I assumed you have basic operations like subtraction already implemented. The above algorithm works for any integer implementation, as long as you can perform the 4 operations mentioned in the beginning. Just replace e.g. `b = b * 2` with your implementation of multiplying uint256 by 2 (which is easy), etc.

Comment: I meant basic bitwise operations. I don't have anything implemented as the only I need is to get modulo.

Comment: Could you please add a way to think about why this works?

Comment: @גלעדברקן
Added explanation